# src\App.js Line 5:3: 'state' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = { 

   }
  render() { 
    return ( 
      <h1>hlw</h1>
     );
  }
}
 
export default App;
```

Comment: I don't get any such errors. See this https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/input.js on https://ikqdn.csb.app/input in `sandbox browser`

Answer (score 0):

You must define state like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { };
   }
   render() {
      return (
        "hlw"
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

I advise you to read [reactsjs Totorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) to find more.